# How to get NetBeans to recognize GLSL types and definitions?

Tags: netbeans, glsl

I'm using NetBeans to code a OpenGL project. I want to keep coding all the source (including GLSL) in NetBeans, but it's showing me a lot of errors since it cannot recognize GLSL types and definitions. I've selected GLSL source files to be treated as C/C++ headers, since the syntax is (mostly) the same in GLSL and C.

[image: netbeans shows errors]

How can I make NetBeans recognize the types and definitions in GLSL? Is there a GLSL C header file somewhere where the types are defined? (I tried Google already for that, no dice)

**EDIT**:

Here's why I'm not using GLSL Syntax Highlighter, I get no content assist:

[image: glsl syntax hightlighter]

Answer (score 2):

I neither code OpenGL nor C/C++, but have you tried the [GLSL Syntax Highlighter](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46515/glsl-syntax-highlighter) plugin?

Comment: GLSL Syntax Highlighter doesnt give me any content assist in GLSL source files, it just colours the keywords appropriately. When treating GLSL source files as "regular files", NetBeans doesn't even recognize words from the same document. Then I'm better off using Notepad++...